# An error prevented faq.liquid from being saved

Tags: json, error-handling, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add a FAQ section with blocks to a Shopify theme. I am able to dynamically add the section without blocks, but once I try to add blocks I keep getting the error message

> "*An error prevented faq.liquid from being saved.*"

I am not sure exactly what the problem is or why its not working since that is a very vague error message.

Here is my code:

```
<hr>
 <div id="section-faq">
  <div class="section-header text-center">
 <h3> {{ section.settings.text-box }} </h3>
</div>

{% for block in section.blocks %}  
<div class="btn" id="faq">   
  <a href="{{ block.settings.text-box }}" class="btn">{{ block.settings.text 
  }}</a>
</div> 
 {% endfor %}

</div>  
<hr>


{% schema %}
{
"name": "faq",
"max_blocks": 6,
"settings": [
    {
    "id": "text-box",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Heading",
    "default": "FAQ"
  }
],
"blocks": [
    {
    "type": "QA",
    "name": "QA",
    "settings": [
        {
        "id": "text-box",
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Question",
        "default": "Add Question"
      },
      {
        "id": "text",
        "type": "richtext",
        "label": "Answer",
        "default": "<p>Add your answer here</p>"
      }
    ]
    }
],
"presets": [
    {
      "name": "FAQ",
      "category": "Faq"
    }
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and created new section and add your code and its working fine for me.